# create rules trade prices for over 200

Tags: magento-1.7

Hi just got to say you are all life savers you know so much.

Ok got a store 1.72 magento and all working ok so I assign a registered person to Trade and they get all the trade prices for trade group for each product.

Problem is or should I say haven't been able to work out.

How do I create this so up to £200 subtotal they get standard prices over gets trade, to stop people buying one top at a time.

I see the discount amount from subtotal but as products they select are random wouldn't be able to calculate that.